# Rails logic best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, separation-of-concerns, rails-models

I had some calculations on my controller like this

```
@travel.food_expenses.map { |e| e.value * e.amount }.sum
```

I know I shouldn't have the application logic on the controller, so I created a method on the Travel model

```
  def self.sum_food_expenses
    self.food_expenses.map { |e| e.value * e.amount }.sum
  end
```

But this will return me the `undefined method sum_food_expenses for TravelsController`

As a workaround I put all those methods on the ApplicationController as:

```
  def sum_food_expenses(travel)
    travel.food_expenses.map { |e| e.value * e.amount }.sum
  end
```

It works but its very very messy, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the travel model, `def self.sum_food_expenses` defined a class method, not an instance method. You want `def sum_food_expenses`. Then in the controller you can call `@travel.sum_food_expenses`.

EDIT: Also, not to be a stickler, but `self.food_expenses.map { |e| e.value * e.amount }.sum` is `O(2n)`, but could be written as `food_expenses.sum { |e| e.value * e.amount }`, which would only be `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks man, but I had to change to `food_expenses.sum("value * amount")`

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is create a method on **instance/object of Travel**.

so in `@travel.sum_food_expenses` the `sum_food_expenses` is a instance method and can be written like

```
def sum_food_expenses
  food_expenses.map { |e| e.value * e.amount }.sum
end
```

Whereas if you wanted to do something similar using **class method** then use `self.your_method`

Which makes the call look like `Travel.your_method`